# Prove/disprove : $f$ has a maximum on a continuous $f: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ if $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Prove/disprove : $f$ has a maximum on a continuous $f: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ if $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ ?

I am utterly clueless by this problem. I know that  $f$ has a maximum on a continuous $f: [0, \infty) \to [0,\infty)$ if $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0.$

But, I think the statement in this case, won't be true. Either way, I can't come up with a counter-example.

Under these circumstances, I get confused when I see the phrase "*Prove/Disprove*" because, I don't know on whether to try finding counter-example first? Or trying to prove the given asssertion first. Any suggestions regarding how to approach these sort of questions will be very helpful for me.

Comment: There are some easy counter-examples.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Can you suggest me some?

Comment: Take say $f(x) = -e^{-x}$? It's negative, increasing and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. The idea? Break the assumption that $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ by allowing $f$ to take negative values, and then notice that if we force the maximum to $+\infty$ then it won't be attained. That's my idea here.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Will $1/(1+x)$  work?

Comment: @ThomasFinley No because it's maximum is attained at $x=0$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Ah! I am sorry. But then, $1/(1+x)$ works, I guess.

Comment: @ThomasFinley I am assuming you meant to write $-\frac{1}{1+x}$, which does indeed work as a counterexample i.e. its maximum is not attained on $[0,\infty)$ and it is continuous.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know how to handle the case $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, the way to approach the case $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is by pondering what might go wrong with the former argument in the latter case.

If the answer is "nothing", great, you are done. Otherwise, you try both fixing the issue as well as turning the issue into a counterexample.

Here we can see that if $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ takes non-negative values at all and satisfies $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, the original proof more or less still works. Thus, we look at functions taking only negative values but tending to $0$ at infinity. Such functions actually can't have a maximum, so if there are any, we've found the desired counterexample.

As discussed in the comments, something like $x \mapsto -\frac{1}{1+x}$ or $x \mapsto -e^{-x}$ meets the criteria of tending to $0$ with all negative values. We've thus arrived at a counterexample.